# What are the Machine Learning Algorithms to use when identifying given words

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning

I'm new to the machine learning and I want to identify the given words using an algorithm.

As an example,

```
construct the triangle ABC such that AB=7cm, BAC=60 and AC=5.5cm
construct the square that is 7cm long each side.
```

in this example I need to identify the words triangle and square.

Comment: What do you mean "identify"? Why those words?

Comment: I need to Identify those words and then I need to categorize them along with their information..As an example if I consider the above example I need to identify ABC is a triangle and AB=7cm, BAC=60 and AC=505cm.

Comment: Please update your question with that information as well any any other context you can give. It would help for you to put more effort into describing your problem. Tell us what you know already about machine learning and what research you've done.

Comment: first I need to identify that in this question they are talking about triangle and square. then after that i want to get the information for the triangle and square. Actually I need to classify those geometric shapes along with their information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems like you want to be the algorithm to be intelligence rather than just identifying couple of words. So in order to that you should go for Natural language processing. There you can identifying nouns of different geometrical objects and in order to gather those information, I mean if you want to list that AB=7, BAC=60 and AC=505 then learn recurrent neural networks (RNN). RNN models can remember what you have said at the beginning of the sentence and identify what details are belongs to that.

ex - Anna lives in Paris and she's fluent in **French**.

RNN can identify the word French.

So just by using a machine learning algorithm it is not possible to identify those words and gather details when provide such a sentence.

You can read this article for further understanding. 
[Understanding LSTM Networks](https://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/)